# Getting an arbitrary element from a set

Tags: java

In many algorithm, you're supposed to iterate over a set of elements, while the set is not empty.

Since you might change the set while iterating it, you typically pull an element out of the set, and then do the iteration, possibly adding or removing elements to or from the set. Here is a typical Java code to do that.

```
Set<Integer> possibleFactors = Sets.newHashSet(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,100);
while (!possibleFactors.isEmpty()) {
    int factor = possibleFactors.iterator().next();
    for (int i=1;i<10;i++) possibleFactors.remove(i*factor);
}
```

**edit:** As asked in the comments, I'll give a better example. I'm iterating through files the user have chosen, and I'm filtering them by checking the permissions of each item. However, as an optimization, if the user don't have permission for a certain directory, I'll remove all the files in it from the set.

```
Set<Path> input = Sets.newHashSet(userSelectedPaths);
while (!input.isEmpty()) {
    Path path = input.iterator.next();
    input.remove(path);
    if (!expensivePermissionCheck(path)) {
        input.removeAll(path.getFiles());
    } else {
        processPath(path);
    }
}
```

However the first line in the loop looks weird. It creates a superfluous `Iterable` objects, when all I want is an arbitrary element from the set, I don't care in which order.

Except the performance, it looks kind of weird, and less readable.

Is there a better alternative? Maybe a different structure altogether?

**edit:** maybe a better formulation would be "How do I pop arbitrary element from a set?"

Comment: You might want to replace `while (!possibleFactors.isEmpty())` with `while (possibleFactors.iterator().hasNext())`

Comment: Your example is confusing: it simply removes each element from the set (because for each iteration of the while loop, the first iteration of the for loop removes '1 * factor'). Might be a good idea to have either a better specification or working code before asking for style suggestions.

Comment: @Arnout, I'm having a working code, but just want to give a general example. Now the code won't remove all elements from the set. I'll give a "real world example" in a minute.

Comment: @Rajeev, but why create an iterator object in vain?

Comment: @Elazar If the remove() ever left even a single entry possibleFactors.isEmpty() would return false, causing a potential infinite loop problem. Besides using iterator doesn't really have any significant overhead, compared to the slight risk involved otherwise.

Comment: @Rajeev, I lost you. If remove leaves an element in the set I want to iterate it. And If the set is none-empty `iterator().hasNext()` is true, so I fail to see the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only access methods for the [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface are via the `iterator()` method or the `toArray()` method.

If you have a [`SortedSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) you can use `first()` or `last()` method to access one item directly.

Comment: `SortedSet`'s implementation assume my elements are `Comparable`, which they aren't. And, I don't mind the order, I just want any order to be OK. `LinkedHashSet` could be OK, but alas, it does not offer any way to get the first element.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's not only not readable but it will also throw an exception if the set is empty.

Before getting the `next()` you should always check `hasNext()` then act based on that.

Comment: It will not throw an exception since the loop checks whether the set is empty.

Comment: @Sean I think he has a point, using next() without using an iterator's hasNext() doesn't throw exceptions as such, but surely runs into an infinite loop; the reason why the OP didn't face a problem so far is since he removes all elements eventually making it empty, but thats just a problem waiting to happen.

Comment: Nope, next() throws NoSuchElementException if there are no more elements. It does not matter whether hasNext() was called. At least, this is the contract; read the javadoc.

Answer (score -2):

In a set there is no particular ordering of elements. You can remove or check the presence of element by providing its value (Set.remove(Object o) or Set.contains(Object o). You may consider to remove all elements from a set, or to paraphrase it keeping elements in set A that are not in set B by using

```
Set.removeAll(Set B);
```

For example

```
Set<Integer> A = new HashSet();
Set<Integer> B = new HashSet();

add numbers from 1-to-10 into A
add even numbers in range [1, 10] to B

A.removeAll(B);
println(A)

will print all odd numbers, eg those that are in A but not in B.
```

Alternatively you can call remove() method which removes element from a set if it exists :

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i += 2) {
   a.remove(i)
}
```

It will have same effect as removeAll() in above example.

Generally, a Set data structure is suitable when you work with collections of unique things and their ordering does not matter. Sets are useful (and fast) if you want to perform Union, Intersection, Diff etc operations on sets. If you have items that may be repeated more that once then you may consider using Multisets (google collections) if you care about ordering of things then Lists will be more helpful (but with worse performance though).

Comment: -1. You said many true things, but I don't see how does it relate to my question. In particular all elements in my set are distinct, I do not need multiset, and I do not see how do I iterate over the set while adding/removing things to it.

Comment: My answer is based on vague formulation of your question. Sorry my mind reading device does not work today.

Comment: don't be so harsh, I didn't mean to offense. If I formulated the question too vaguely I'll be glad if you'd help me clarify it. But I'm not sure a vague answer will help.